# Django Model is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

Im trying to return a dictionary of Django models in JSON format.

I have tried serializers, model_to_dict, json.dump and can't seem to get it working.

a small snippet of the code:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = (Venue.objects.all())
        location = self.request.query_params.get('location', None)
        latitude = location.split('S')[0]
        longitude = location.split('S')[1]
        venue_gaps = {}
        for venue in queryset.iterator():
            locationArray = [y.strip() for y in venue.postcode.split(',')]
            distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(latitude) + " " + str(longitude)], [str(locationArray[0]) + " " + str(locationArray[1])], mode='driving')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]
            m = distance["distance"]["value"]
            venue_gaps[m] = venue
        sorted_venues = dict(sorted(venue_gaps.items()))
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(sorted_venues))
```

the dictionary I create is a {int:object, int:object, int:object, ....}

I want this to be returned as the response. I keep getting issues such as "TypeError: Object of type object is not JSON serializable"

Comment: the dictionary is test_dict, I'm initialising it in the second line. This is my first ever python/django project so im very new to this. thanks for looking at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `django.core.serializers`:

```
from django.core import serializers

qs = YourModel.objects.filter(foo='bar')
serialized_qs = serializers.serialize('json', qs)

print(serialized_qs)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/

Comment: I tried this, but it returns the objects in one json string. I need to sort the objects into the dictionary first, and then serialise it. How can I serialise the diction of {int:Oject}

Comment: Call `obj.__dict__` or use django rest framework serializers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: when I call x.__dict__ when im adding it to the dictionary I get the error "TypeError: Object of type ModelState is not JSON serializable". Did I do this in the right place?

Comment: Call it on a model instance, e.g `obj = YourModel.objects.get(id=123)`

Comment: I've updated my code snippet with the full function. I've tried your suggestion but maybe im not doing it correctly. Sorry this is my first Django project!

Comment: ```venue_gaps[m] = model_to_dict(venue)```

Comment: ahh thank you so much! I tried this at one stage but must have screwed something else up! thank you for your patience ☺️

Comment: You are welcome :) Don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Simpler issue I believe:

```
 return JsonResponse(json.dumps(sorted_venues))
```

is redundant, this should work:

```
return JsonResponse(sorted_venues)
```